# XSLT unparsed text replacement or formatting for bold or font change

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want the unparsed text to be formatted for bold characters or increase font-size based on the tag the non-working example here is for replace the searched text with bold characters Example string (this post strips all the html bold characters): 
    'test  how to  when bold  when there is more  than one place to bold'

Can you please advice what is wrong here

```
<xsl:variable name="tcline" select="unparsed-text('generic_tc.txt','UTF-8')"/>
  <xsl:analyze-string select="$tcline" regex="\'<b>'(.*?)\'<b>'">
     <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace($tcline,'\"<b>"(.*?)\"<b>"','<em>$1\/em/g;')"/>
   </xsl:matching-substring>
   <xsl:non-matching-substring>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
```

- Also what will be a good place to test xsl when your template is in server somewhere?

Comment: Consider to post a sample of the input format and the corresponding result (plain text? or XML or HTML) you want to create.

Comment: this is for the generation of pdf document on ebusiness the sample text file am trying to use is as follows (so where ever the <b> is found I want the document to appear in bold):: <b>Terms and conditions<b> The following are the terms of <b>usage<b> of the product and some dummy data